# Send SMS Arduino Uno + SIM900A shield

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, gsm, port-mapping

I am working on a module to send messages. I write the message on the serial monitor + phone number and I have to send the message to the line.

***Question:***

How to send messages through the SIM900A shield?

***Problem:***
What am I doing wrong in my code? Because I do not get an error but it does not send the SMS using the shield.

Try:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(6, 7);
char msg;

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600); // Setting the baud rate of GSM Module  
  Serial.begin(9600); // Setting the baud rate of Serial Monitor (Arduino)
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()>0)
    switch(Serial.read()) {
      mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
      delay(1000); // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
      mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+XXXXXXXXX\"\r"); // mobile number
      delay(1000);
      mySerial.println("sim900a sms");// The SMS text you want to send
      delay(100);
      mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
      delay(1000);
    }
  if (mySerial.available()>0) Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

***This is my shield***
[image: This is my shield]

Other try:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(6, 7);
char msg;

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);  // Setting the baud rate of GSM Module  
  Serial.begin(9600); // Setting the baud rate of Serial Monitor (Arduino)
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
  delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+XXXXXXXXX\"\r"); // mobile number
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.println("sim900a sms");// The SMS text you want to send
  delay(100);
  mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: And the question/problem is?

Comment: There is still no question.

Comment: now? help me please

Answer (score 1):

There was not really a question, but I do notice there is no case's in your switch statement..

example from [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SwitchCase)

```
// do something different depending on the range value:
  switch (range) {
    case 0:    // your hand is on the sensor
      Serial.println("dark");
      break;
    case 1:    // your hand is close to the sensor
      Serial.println("dim");
      break;
    case 2:    // your hand is a few inches from the sensor
      Serial.println("medium");
      break;
    case 3:    // your hand is nowhere near the sensor
      Serial.println("bright");
      break;
  }
  delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
```

Comment: a need send message to shield

Comment: Are you wanted to send all those commands when ANY byte is received from Serial.read()?

Comment: the switch is to see if there is data or not in the serial, the question is. How to send an SMS with the shield?

Comment: @R.Fernandez That's not how `switch` statement works.

Comment: println() also adds a newline ( \n ) to the end of what you are sending, not sure if your module expects that or not, but you also have a return ( \r ) in one of your messages,   need to check to see exactly what the module expects